# Sidemenu stops working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, side-menu

I created the Ionic application from the menu

```
ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

On one of the pages there will be a test, and I want that after the end of the test there is a mandatory page with a comment. With which the user could not get anywhere, until he filled out the comment.

I created a test page and a comment page

I decided to use the Modals

On the test page there is a button that opens a page of comments

```
finishTest() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('CommentPage');
    modal.present();
}
```

On the comments page, I want to go to the main page after sending

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
}
```

The problem is that when I turn to the main page my sidemenu stops working.

Has anyone been confronted with this problem?
How can it be solved?
Can you use something else instead of Modals?

Comment: please swipe left to right of home page then you show side menu

Comment: This does not work, like pressing a button
                                                   `<button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that when you open a page as a Modal, **that modal has its own navigation stack**. So when you do `this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);` inside of the modal, you're actually setting that page as the root page of the navigation stack from the modal, where the side menu does not work.

In order to fix that, you'd need to **get a reference of the root NavController in your app**, like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({... })
class YourModalPage {

  constructor(public appCtrl: App, ...) {}

  pushPage() {
    this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(HomePage);
  }

  setPageAsRoot() {
    this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(HomePage);
  }

}
```

You can find some more information about working with different navigation stacks **[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-an-overlay-component)**.

Comment: And if we move from the HomePage to the new page 'ProgPage' (`this.navCtrl.setRoot('ProgPage');`), which is not in the menu, and then we get to the Modals 'CommentPage', then the transition from modal to the HomePage, does not work

Answer (score 0):

**You need to change in `CommentPage`**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController,public appCtrl: App) {}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(HomePage);
}
```

I think your problem will be solve...